# Delete duplicate values array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to delete duplicate arrays.. but it seems not to work...

this is my array:

```
array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 141
        [yt] => 5
        [PHD] => Jan
        [type] => Mercedes
        [aid] => 5
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [yt] => 5
        [PHD] => Jan
        [type] => Mercedes
        [aid] => 5
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [yt] => 5
        [PHD] => Jan
        [type] => Mercedes
        [aid] => 5
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 10
        [yt] => 5
        [PHD] => Jan
        [type] => Mercedes
        [aid] => 5
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [yt] => 5
        [PHD] => Peter
        [type] => Audi
        [aid] => 5
    )
)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[5] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [yt] => 5
        [PHD] => Peter
        [type] => Audi
        [aid] => 5
    )
```

The array creates with a SQL query so I foreach the array:

```
  foreach($All_cars as $key=>$row) {
  .....
  print_r($All_cars);
  }
```

So that outputs the whole array.

I tried this but no effect.

```
 $result = array_unique($All_cars );
```

I hope you guys can help me... cause I tried this 1 whole day already.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why don't you put DISTINCT in your query?

Comment: From the DOCS: `Note: Note that array_unique() is not intended to work on multi dimensional arrays.`

Comment: @MayankPandeyz cause I use the query for serval things.

Comment: @Jeff Are there another solutions or manipulates to use unique?

Comment: check @http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php this link may help you

Comment: @ayush thanks for the link.. The array_unique works only if everthing of the array is the same. I just need to recognize when one key is the same.

Comment: The link provided by @ayush is the exact solution you might be looking for. I also had an assumption that if you need to remove all the data with duplication leaving only the data that's not duplicated. Right?

Comment: @Perumal93 I forgot to implement the id. So every array has a identifier ID. The array_unique removes only if the arrays are exaclty the same.. I have to find out a another solution that just recognize the key [type] or [PHD] . But thanks.

Comment: Ah. This is what I was thinking why ID of each array had same.

Comment: Sorry my bad :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
$input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $input)));
```

Or

```
$array = [
    [
        'id' => '123',
        'foo' => 'aaa',
        'bar' => 'bbb'
    ],
    [
        'id' => '123',
        'foo' => 'ccc',
        'bar' => 'ddd'
    ],
    [
        'id' => '567',
        'foo' => 'eee',
        'bar' => 'fff'
    ]
];

$ids = array_column($array, 'id');
$ids = array_unique($ids);
$array = array_filter($array, function ($key) use ($ids) {
    return in_array($key, array_keys($ids));
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

The result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 123
            [foo] => aaa
            [bar] => bbb
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 567
            [foo] => eee
            [bar] => fff
        )

)
```

Or

if you need to eliminate duplicates on specific keys, such as a mysqli id, here's a simple funciton

```
function search_array_compact($data,$key){
    $compact = [];
    foreach($data as $row){
        if(!in_array($row[$key],$compact)){
            $compact[] = $row;
        }
    }
    return $compact;
}
```

**Note**
You can pass an array of keys and add an outer foreach, but it will be 2x slower per additional key.

Or
You can use an associative array.

```
$temp_array = array();
foreach ($array as &$v) {
    if (!isset($temp_array[$v['name']]))
        $temp_array[$v['name']] =& $v;
}
```

This creates a temporary array, using `$v['name']` as the key. If there is already an element with the same key, it is not added to the temporary array.

You can convert the associative array back to a sequential array, using

```
$array = array_values($temp_array);
```

Example code and output: http://codepad.org/zHfbtUrl

Comment: The second one :p with the array_filter

Comment: You need to correct the second method. Swap the variables in the parameter of callback function passed in `array_filter` to avoid misconception. The order of parameter names should be like `function ($value, $key) use ($ids) {` and also `return in_array($key, array_keys($ids));`. Also, you don't need to use `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH` if you're only going to use key of the array and `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY` is enough and remove the `$value` parameter leaving only `$key` parameter.

Comment: @Perumal93  Thanks, I changed it. :)

Comment: @Perumal93 you can edit answer if sure,i've not tested.

Comment: The FILTER_USE_KEY takes less memory so It's way faster.

Comment: Using `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH` when only key of the elements are used rather than values is a kind of quite more memory consumption and using `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY` is alone enough only if you're going to work with keys because this avoids redundant code and also prevents from memory consumption keeping performance as much simpler as it could.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for($i=0;  $i < count($array); $i++)
{
    for($j=0;  $j < count($array); $j++)
    {
        if($array[$i] == $array[$j])
        {
            unset $array[$i];
        }
    }
}
```